# JQuery toggle classes on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need my button to toggle between Current Events and Future Events when clicked. Currently, the text on the button changes, but the actual events on the page will not toggle.

On page load, the current events and "Current Event" button are shown. When I click the "Current Events" button, the button text switches to "Future Events". The actual events under each race type are supposed to switch over to the future events, but they are not toggling. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Thank you!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>FV Runners</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    .panel {
        color: orange;
    }

    #a:hover {
        color: gray;
    }

    .hide{
display:none;
}

.future{
display:none;
}

.button {
float:right;
margin-right:110px;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">


    <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
</div>

<div id="main"></div>

<button class="button">Current Events</button>
<div id="pics">
    <div class="race_box">      
    <img src="images/run1.jpg" id="5kpic" /><br />

  <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>


        <div class="current" id="5k">
            <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
            <ul>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Mini Sprint</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>10/30/18, Memorial Park, Appleton</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Iron Horse</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>11/6/18, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Twilight Trail</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>11/13/18, River's Edge Park, Wrightstown</p>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>

                   <div class="future" id="5K">
            <h3>5K / 10K Events</h3>
            <ul>

             <li class="accordion" id="a">Snowball Sprint</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>1/14/19, Mosquito Hill, New London</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Winter Warrior</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>2/06/19, Bay Beach, Green Bay</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Big Chill Run</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>2/24/19, Mid Valley Golf Course, De Pere</p>
                </div>

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="race_box">
    <img src="images/run2.jpg" id="halfpic" /></button><br />
  <figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>


        <div class="current" id="half">
            <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
            <ul>

                <li class="accordion" id="a">Fox River Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>10/15/18, Pierce Park, Appleton</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">N.E.W. Half Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>10/29/18, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Winnebago Run</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>11/27/18, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
                </div>

            </ul>
        </div>
                    <div class="future" id="half" >
            <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
            <ul>

             <li class="accordion" id="a">Frosty Indoor Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>1/15/19, TryIt Ice Arena, Neenah</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Valentine Run</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>2/12/19, Green Isle Park, De Pere</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Snowball Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>3/03/19, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
                </div>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="race_box">
    <img src="images/run3.jpg" id="fullpic" /><br />
  <figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>


        <div class="current" id="full">
            <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
            <ul>

                <li class="accordion" id="a">Cheesehead Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>9/24/18, Pamperin Park, Green Bay</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Chain O'Lakes Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>10/29/18, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Fox Cities Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>11/12/18, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
                </div>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="future" id="full">
            <h3>Marathon Events</h3>
            <ul>
             <li class="accordion" id="a">Trailbreaker Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>4/02/19, Leach Amphitheatre, Oshkosh</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Jailbreak Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>4/16/19, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Cellcom Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>5/20/19, Lombardi Atrium, Green Bay</p>
                </div>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
onload=hide;
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function() {
    hide(this);
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
}
}
function hide(e){
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    if(e!==acc[i] && acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.value.indexOf("hide")<0)
      acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
}
}
</script>

<script>
    $('.button').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('.button');
    if($this.hasClass('.button')){
        $this.text('Current Events');           
    } else {
        $this.text('Future Events');
    }
});


</script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the class of your current events button?

Comment: try without a dot in toggleClass('button') and hasClass('button')

Comment: "current" for current events and "future" for future events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. Add this two line in your onclick.

(to answer your question 'what I am doing wrong?'--> is that you are doing nothing with the element(no hide no show) and that is what wrong)

```
$('.future').toggle();
$('.current').toggle();
```

**[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** will hide elements if they are visible and show element if they are hidden.

```js
onload = hide;
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        hide(this);
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
    }
}

function hide(e) {
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        if (e !== acc[i] && acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.value.indexOf("hide") < 0)
            acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
    }
}
$('.button').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('button');
    $('.future').toggle();
    $('.current').toggle();
    if ($this.hasClass('button')) {
        $this.text('Current Events');
    } else {
        $this.text('Future Events');
    }
});
```

```css
.panel {
            color: orange;
        }

        #a:hover {
            color: gray;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

        .future {
            display: none;
        }

        .button {
            margin-right: 110px;

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>FV Runners</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">


        <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="main"></div>

    <button class="button">Current Events</button>
    <div id="pics">



        <div class="current" id="5k">
            <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
            <ul>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Mini Sprint</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>10/30/18, Memorial Park, Appleton</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Iron Horse</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>11/6/18, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Twilight Trail</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>11/13/18, River's Edge Park, Wrightstown</p>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="future" id="5K">
            <h3>5K / 10K Events</h3>
            <ul>

                <li class="accordion" id="a">Snowball Sprint</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>1/14/19, Mosquito Hill, New London</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Winter Warrior</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>2/06/19, Bay Beach, Green Bay</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Big Chill Run</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>2/24/19, Mid Valley Golf Course, De Pere</p>
                </div>

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="race_box">


        <div class="current" id="half">
            <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
            <ul>

                <li class="accordion" id="a">Fox River Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>10/15/18, Pierce Park, Appleton</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">N.E.W. Half Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>10/29/18, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Winnebago Run</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>11/27/18, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
                </div>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="future" id="half">
            <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
            <ul>

                <li class="accordion" id="a">Frosty Indoor Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>1/15/19, TryIt Ice Arena, Neenah</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Valentine Run</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>2/12/19, Green Isle Park, De Pere</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Snowball Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>3/03/19, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
                </div>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="race_box">


        <div class="current" id="full">
            <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
            <ul>

                <li class="accordion" id="a">Cheesehead Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>9/24/18, Pamperin Park, Green Bay</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Chain O'Lakes Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>10/29/18, Bay Beach Park, Green Bay</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Fox Cities Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>11/12/18, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
                </div>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="future" id="full">
            <h3>Marathon Events</h3>
            <ul>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Trailbreaker Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>4/02/19, Leach Amphitheatre, Oshkosh</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Jailbreak Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>4/16/19, Menominee Park, Oshkosh</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <li class="accordion" id="a">Cellcom Marathon</li>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>5/20/19, Lombardi Atrium, Green Bay</p>
                </div>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your different events have classes 'future' and 'current' you could use those to show and hide the events as the button is pushed.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('.button');
    if($this.hasClass('.button')){
        $this.text('Current Events'); 
        $(".current").hide();
        $(".future").show();
    } else {
        $this.text('Future Events');
                $(".future").hide();
        $(".current").show();
    }
});
```

Here's this solution in action: https://jsfiddle.net/Rikkokiri/6r8cke0y/5/